# My points are drawn at 0 latitude, 0 longitude

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-android-api

This is my click listener on the map:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSingleTap(MotionEvent point) {
        Point mapPoint=view.toMapPoint(point.getX(), point.getY());
        SpatialReference sp = SpatialReference.create(SpatialReference.WKID_WGS84);
        Point p1Done=(Point) GeometryEngine.project(mapPoint, view.getSpatialReference(), sp);
        UtilsMapa.addPoint(p1Done, view, "Marker",view.getGraphicLayer());
        return super.onSingleTap(point);
    }
```

The addPoint method:

```
public static void addPoint(Point point, MapViewExt mView, String textMarker, GraphicsLayer gLayer){
    SimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED, 10, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CIRCLE);
    TextSymbol bassRockTextSymbol = new TextSymbol(10, textMarker, BLUE, TextSymbol.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT,
            TextSymbol.VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
    //When reaching this line, point has 0=-3.0246720297389555 1=40.83564363734672, which is where I tapped the screen
    Graphic graphic=new Graphic(point,simpleMarker);
    gLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
}
```

The graphic IS added (a red spot) but it is drawn at 0,0 coords... Why is that? How can I get the point drawn in the proper place?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

Don't project the point into WGS 1984. Use the point that `MapView.toMapPoint(double, double)` returns to you.

## Detailed explanation

In ArcGIS Runtime 10.2.x for Android, a [`Point`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geometry/Point.html) object doesn't keep track of its spatial reference. It's really just an x-value and a y-value. If you give a `Point` to the `MapView`, the `MapView` will assume that the `Point` is in the same spatial reference as the map, which by default is usually in Web Mercator.

Here's what your code is doing:

```
Point mapPoint=view.toMapPoint(point.getX(), point.getY());
```

`mapPoint` is now a point in `MapView`'s spatial reference, which is probably Web Mercator. The point is probably some number of millions of meters from (0, 0), but since the `Point` class is blissfully unaware of spatial references, it just contains an x-value in the millions and a y-value in the millions, **with no units**.

```
SpatialReference sp = SpatialReference.create(SpatialReference.WKID_WGS84);
Point p1Done=(Point) GeometryEngine.project(mapPoint, view.getSpatialReference(), sp);
```

`p1Done` is now a point in WGS 1984, which is some number of degrees from (0, 0). You have a comment that says the x-value is -3.0246720297389555 and the y-value is 40.83564363734672, or maybe the other way around, but the important point is that the x-value is between -180 and 180 and the y-value is between -90 and 90, **with no units**.

```
UtilsMapa.addPoint(p1Done, view, "Marker",view.getGraphicLayer());
```

Your helper method is called with `p1Done`, which is called `point` in your helper method.

```
Graphic graphic=new Graphic(point,simpleMarker);
```

A graphic is created with a point whose x-value is -3.0246720297389555 and y-value is 40.83564363734672.

```
gLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
```

The graphic is added to a graphics layer, which has the spatial reference of the map that contains it, which is probably Web Mercator. The map correctly displays the point -3.024672029738955 **meters** west of (0, 0) and 40.83564363734672 **meters** north of (0, 0).

### Side note: upgrade to ArcGIS Runtime 100.x

If you had used Runtime 100.x, you might have avoided this problem, since Runtime 100.x geometries, including [`Point`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/geometry/Point.html), do keep track of their spatial reference.